# $f(z)={2z+1\over 5z+3}$ maps

Tags: complex-analysis

Define

$H^{+}=\{z:y>0\}$

$H^{-}=\{z:y<0\}$

$L^{+}=\{z:x>0\}$

$L^{-}=\{z:x<0\}$

$f(z)={2z+1\over 5z+3}$  maps

$1.$ $H^+\to H^+$ and $H^-\to H^-$

$2$. $H^+\to H^-$ and $H^-\to H^+$

$3.$ $H^+\to L^-$ and $H^-\to L^+$

$4.$ $H^+\to L^+$ and $H^-\to L^-$

If I take $z\in H^{+}$ then ${3\over z}\in H^{-}\Rightarrow {3\over z}+5={5z+3\over z}\in H^{-}$ Could any one tell me how to proceed then?

Comment: See where it maps $1$ and $i$. All the other values have to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ maps $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ it is one of the first two options. Since $f(i)=(1+2i)/(3+5i)=(3-5i)(1+2i)/(\cdots)^2 = (i+\cdots)/\cdots$ it's 1.

Answer (score 1):

Since $z$ is real, then $f(z)$ is real, and $z$ is pure imaginary, then $f(z)$ is not real or pure imaginary. So the answer is between 1. and 2.

Put $z=i \in H^+$, $f(z)\in H^+$, so the answer is 1.